# How do I assign values from one data frame to another based on row value using R?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have the following datasets DF1 and DF2. I am looking to assign values from Col3 from DF2 in the order it's in to rows in DF1. Please note that from As and Cs get unique values from Col3 but all Bs get one value, nothing specific, but the first one that is available, in this example it is 11 as the As exhausted values 1-9. The values from Col3 are to be assigned to DF1 in the order they are in(ascending) for as long as there are rows left in DF1 that need a value. (Please see desired output).

DF1

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 99 | A1 |
| 99 | A2 |
| 99 | A3 |
| 99 | A4 |
| 99 | A5 |
| 99 | B1 |
| 99 | B2 |
| **98** | B3 |
| **98** | B4 |
| 99 | C1 |
| 99 | C2 |

DF2

| Col3 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 7 |
| 9 |
| 11 |
| 13 |
| 15 |
| 17 |
| 19 |
| 21 |
| 23 |

**Desired Output**

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | A1 | 1 |
| 99 | A2 | 3 |
| 99 | A3 | 5 |
| 99 | A4 | 7 |
| 99 | A5 | 9 |
| 99 | B1 | 11 |
| 99 | B2 | 11 |
| **98** | B3 | 13 |
| **98** | B4 | 13 |
| 99 | C1 | 15 |
| 99 | C2 | 17 |

This is part of a very large data set and I usually do this in excel manually. I am running into a wall in R and could really use the help. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `As and Cs get unique values from Col3 but all Bs get one value.`  Is there any criteria for selecting the one value  for 'B'?  It is not clear

Comment: Hi Akrun, I have edited my question to clarify. To answer your question, there is no criteria for selecting the one value for B, it will get the first value available from DF2, in this example it is 11. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dplyr,

```r
library(dplyr)
DF1 %>%
  mutate(
    ltr1 = substr(Col2, 1, 1),
    rn = cumsum(ltr1 != "B" | (lag(ltr1, default=ltr1[1]) != "B" | Col1 != lag(Col1, default=Col1[1]))),
    Col3 = DF2$Col3[rn]
  ) %>%
  select(-ltr1, -rn)
#      Col1 Col2 Col3
# 1      99   A1    1
# 2      99   A2    3
# 3      99   A3    5
# 4      99   A4    7
# 5      99   A5    9
# 6      99   B1   11
# 7      99   B2   11
# 8  **98**   B3   13
# 9  **98**   B4   13
# 10     99   C1   15
# 11     99   C2   17
```

The reason I went with literal row-number extraction from `DF2` is that we have no other "join" criteria.

Walk-through:

- `cumsum(.)` is an incrementer of sorts: when the condition is true, then `rn` is incremented. This should sequence by 1 for every row that does not contain a `"B*"` in `Col2`.
- `ltr1 != "B" | lag(..) != "B"` ensures that we won't allow `cumsum` to increment when in a `"B"` row or if the previous row is a `"B"` row.
- *added* `Col1 != lag(Col1)` adds that a change in `Col1` results in incrementing the row number (`rn`) used in `DF2`.
- (the use of `rn` as a name is completely arbitrary, meant to be a throw-away name that is removed later)

Comment: Hi Evans, although this worked, can you please explain your logic in simple english behind the line with cumulative function: cumsum(ltr1 != "B" | lag(ltr1, default=ltr1[1]) != "B")? and why you named it "rn"? Thank you again!

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I was curious if rn stood for anything, it would have helped me understand your thought process. Thanks anyways, you have just saved me some serious hours at work!

Comment: `r`ow `n`umber (perhaps not a technically-correct acronym), though it could have easily be `x` (for nothing), `quux` (because it's unlikely to appear in real data and is just silly), `foo`, or any other number of clear, unlikely-to-collide, temporary-variable names. :-)

Comment: Ahhh I see, thanks again for your help and being super responsive :)!

Comment: Hi Evans, I ran into an edge case and made an edit to the original post to reflect that. I changed two rows of 99s to 98s in Col1. This will now affect the corresponding value in Col3. Now Bs for 99s and 98s will get their own set of repeating values in Col3 as shown. Is there a way to accommodate this in the original program?

Comment: does order matter? That is, if Col1 it 99, 98, 99, 98, does it change the output?

Comment: Yeah! All 99 Bs should have one value and all 98 Bs should have one value regardless of their order

Comment: See my edit, @Sundew. Just need to add `... | Col1 != lag(Col1, default=Col1[1])` to within the `cumsum` step.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Is there a book/course you recommend where I can get deeper into R for projects like this one?

Comment: I don't know of a book or tutorial that covers this level of "bespoke" filtering, sorry ... I wish I did, frankly, I've been getting more questions about that these days

Comment: That’s very fair. I think I just need to start with the fundamentals. Can’t beat years of learning and applying fundamentals by simply grinding a book or two. Thanks again!